# Sorting questions with nested resources using jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

There are many questions already on this topic but I cannot seem to find anything that works. Using [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised) railscast, I'm trying to sort a list of questions using jquery-ui but like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884753/rails-3-2-jquery-sortable-list-500-error-with-nested-resources) question my nested resources are confusing things.

I have three models: posts, comments and questions.

Post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :questions, :through :comments
end
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :questions
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

The list of questions I'd like to sort is on the ordered_path view (posts/:id/ordered). Here is the posts controller:

Posts_controller.rb

```
def ordered 
 @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @ordered = @post.questions.where(:hide => true).where(:recommend => true).order("position")
end
```

and questions_controller.rb:

```
def sort
  params[:question].each_with_index do |id, index|
  Question.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
end
  render nothing: true
end
```

I believe I've followed the railscast correctly. I've added a 'position' column to questions. I added this to the routes:

routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
 resources :questions do
  collection { post :sort }
 end
end
```

And in my view I have this

posts/ordered.html.erb

```
<ul id="questions" data-update-url="<%= sort_comment_questions_path %>">
 <% @ordered.each do |question| %>
   <%= content_tag_for :li, question do %>
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
     <%= question.body %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Lastly, posts.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#questions').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    handle: '.handle'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

My problem(s) is that I am unsure what to pass into the data-update-url (to get rid of the 'no route matches' error) or if that's even the correct path in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing in your code, change the line

```
@ordered = @post.questions.where(:hide => true).where(:recommend => true).order("position")
```

to

```
@ordered = @post.questions.where(:hide => true, :recommend => true).order("position")
```

As you typically only want one where() call if you can help it. Sometimes you will need to add one conditionally which is fine. In an if block for example.

As far as your route error, run `rake routes` in terminal, and you will see output of all the route methods, the params they accept, the HTTP method, and what controller#action it hits.

The important thing to note about nested resources, is the nested resource is applied to a "member" of the parent. So in your case what your two resources blocks are generating are:

```
GET /comments/:comment_id/questions questions#index
GET /comments/:comment_id/questions/:id questions#show
POST /comments/:comment_id/questions/sort questions#sort
```

So in your erb tags in the data attribute, you need to add the comment to it:

```
<ul id="questions" data-update-url="<%= sort_comment_questions_path(@comment) %>">
```

The problem though is that you are using this at the post model level, which has many comments. So what you probably want is this:

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions
end

resources :posts do
  member do
    post "sort" => "questions#sort", :as => "sort_questions"
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<ul id="questions" data-update-url="<%= sort_questions_post_path(@post) %>">
```

Comment: Great, that basically fixed it. (Just had to change sort_post_questions_path to sort_post_path). A fellow young canadian guy appreciates the help :)

Comment: Ah okay. The as should have made it work as i had it. But it's definitely not required :)